# Setting Asp.net Core with Angular2 in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, typescript, angular, frontend, backend

I have tried many ways to set-up a Angular2 together with TypeScript in Visual Studio using ASP.NET Core. There is so many different ways in internet to do this by setting up npm config, gulp etc. But most of them really complex and don't work (at least for me), is any BASIC way to set-up Angular2 into it? Without using complex stuff? I want to be able to create an Empty Core project and set-up an Angular2 and start work with both in the same project.

Comment: See if this link is useful - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html

Answer (score 0):

Agree, all these complex tools are not neccesory.
Most of them are angular2 experts, know little of asp.net core and hit wall when put two togeter.

here is my simple solution you can try: https://github.com/Longfld/ASPNETCoreAngular2

Just remember : if you modify ng2 code,  run "npm start" before run "dotnet run". And it works for both Visual Studio and Visusl Studio code